# Yahoo Finance Chart Android - How receive a big chart?

Tags: java, android, charts, yahoo, finance

I programmed in a Stockwatch Android but when I send a get on yahoo (http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/t?s=yhoo) I get a little graphic (190x95), but if I send this (http:// ichart.finance.yahoo.com / b? s = YHOO) increases the size (512x288).
There are other parameters to use?
Thanks a lot.